# One line with two styles in SwiftUI Chart

Tags: swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

Is it possible to make the Chart with one line that will have two styles like on this picture?

[image: chart line example]

I tried this, but it always selects only one style.

```
func strokeStyleByID(thenID: Int) -> StrokeStyle {
        if thenID > 0 {
            return StrokeStyle(dash: [5]) // dashed line for future
        } else {
            return StrokeStyle(dash: [0]) // solid line for past
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you draw two lines, each with their own style?

Comment: When I use two ForEach{} structs, it's not working. Even for colors. But different `.symbol` is working, but this is not what required.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and share a [example]